# When I use a PropertDrawer for a List it still showes the size field and the dropdown. How can I fix this?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I wrote a code where I wanted to give Lists another look in the Inspector. Therefore I am using the `CustomPropertyDrawer`. The Problem is that even thought i override the `OnGui()` method it still prints the Dropdown and the Sizefield. How can i remove them too?
[image]

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using UnityEngine;
public class CursorChange : MonoBehaviour {

    [FormatedList]
    public List<Texture2D> crosshairs;

    public int crosshairWidth = 64;
    public int crosshairHeight = 64;

    private int selected;
    private Transform myTransform;
    private Camera myCamera;

    void Start() {
        myCamera = GameObject.FindWithTag("MainCamera").GetComponent<Camera>();
        myTransform = transform; //So you don't GetComponent your transform with every OnGUI call
        Cursor.visible = false;

    }

    void OnGUI() {
        if (Time.time != 0 && Time.timeScale != 0)
            GUI.DrawTexture(
                new Rect(Screen.width * 0.5f - crosshairWidth * 0.5f, Screen.height * 0.5f - crosshairHeight * 0.5f, crosshairWidth, crosshairHeight), 
                crosshairs[selected]
            );
    }
}
```

```
using System;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEditor;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UIElements;

[CustomPropertyDrawer(typeof(FormatedListAttribute))]
public class FormatedList : PropertyDrawer {

    public override void OnGUI(Rect position, SerializedProperty property, GUIContent label) {

    }

    public static System.Type GetType(SerializedProperty property) {
        System.Type parentType = property.serializedObject.targetObject.GetType();
        System.Reflection.FieldInfo fi = parentType.GetField(property.propertyPath);
        return fi.FieldType;
    }
}
```

Comment: well ... where is your property drawer implementation?

Comment: Updated it now so u can see

Comment: as far as I can tell something is wrong with the link to this PropertyDrawer => `OnGUI` is never even called ... can you debug and confirm that?

Comment: `OnGui` gets called. As you can see the array-size is on 3 and there a 3 blank spaces. When i don' t override `OnGui` it is not blank and there are 3 `Texture2d` fields

Comment: Oh I see! Afaik this doesn't work for Lists and Arrays at all - at least not how you would expect it: For these two types your `PropertyDrawer` and `OnGUI` **only refers to the contained type/elements**! You can't override the label and size field using a `PropertyDrawer`. You would instead have to go through a `CustomEditor` for `CursorChange` here

Comment: So whenever I want that look for a List i would have to write it again? Cause i have already done a Customeditor for my Camera and now tryed to make it portable so i just add the Property and it works... Why did unity do it like that...

Comment: because as said for `List<>` and `Array` the behavior is different. The reason is probably that it is quite non-trivial to be able to serialize generic types ;) So we can already be lucky that Unity found a general way to do so in the inspector etc

Comment: Mhm thats still sad. I mean that would have been 1 hour work for them or less but now u can not even do that with a 10 hours workaround... 
Thx for your answares

Comment: The other alternative would be to have a wrapper class for the list and make a property drawer for it .. but you will notice very soon that this is actually pretty hard .. as said it is anything else than trivial to be able to serialize generic types (`List<T>`) ...

Comment: Hey I kinda revert what I said: It is kind of possible .. but not the way you want it. You **can** overwrite the drawing of **all** lists for a specific type or simply **all** inspectors globally! All you need is basically a [`CustomEditor(typeof(UnityEngine.Object), true, isFallback = true)`](https://medium.com/developers-writing/how-about-having-nice-arrays-and-lists-in-unity3d-by-default-e4fba13d1b50) you could then still check if a list/array additionally also has your attribute and only then use your custom drawer method!

Comment: Thank you very much will try it soon. When i have managed to code what I want i will also post it :D

Comment: I have searched a little bit but have not found out how i have to implement that. Do u have an example which you could send me?

Comment: It is on there in the link .. it refers to [CustomEditorBase.cs](https://gist.github.com/t0chas/34afd1e4c9bc28649311) there is also already an example for getting the property's attributes (it is commented out) a simple `if(attr.Contains(XY)` should probably do the trick